# where/how to setup configuration resources for Tomcat .war files

Tags: java, configuration, tomcat

I have a source tree for a .war file that I need to modify so that I can add some application-specific configuration info (in this case a jdbc connection string, but I may have other properties-like resources). What are the best practices for where to put configuration info and how to access this from within the Servlet?

I'm guessing this [Tomcat configuration reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) has something to do with it, but my eyes glaze over when I try to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the specific case of a JDBC connection string, I would recommend using a Tomcat-managed connection pool instead.  You can read more about doing this here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

It's more work, but I think in the long run it will serve you better.

Comment: thanks... you're probably right about the long run, but this is probably the only Tomcat app I will be working on for a long time + I don't have too much spare time to figure out how to tweak my application. The apache docs aren't very clear.

Comment: this makes a little more sense now after spending time pulling my hair out (alas...) and after looking at the JIRA server.xml. How do I access the DataSource from within my Java app, though? The example page gives an example of JSP but not of Java code.

Comment: They include a couple examples further down (e.g. in the PostgreSQL section, step 4).

Comment: There's another example within this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119817/can-i-set-the-jdbc-isolation-level-from-a-tomcat-context

Comment: This is a link only answer. Could you please enrich it with an excerpt from the linked source?

Answer (score 5):

For web app configuration you can place the config on the classpath somewhere.  Then you can get to it from your application with [getResourceAsStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) or if you prefer Spring:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:my-config.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

There are a number of places you can put the properties on the classpath in Tomcat.  in order it looks at:

```
/WEB-INF/classes of your web application 
/WEB-INF/lib/*. jar of your web application 
$CATALINA_HOME/common/classes 
$CATALINA_HOME/common/endorsed/*.jar 
$CATALINA_HOME/common/i18n/*.jar 
$CATALINA_HOME/common/lib / *. jar 
$CATALINA_BASE/shared/classes 
$CATALINA_BASE/shared/lib/*.jar
```

For example, if you put my-config.properties both in a .jar file and in WEB-INF/classes the one in WEB-INF/classes will be used.  You could use this mechanism to default to test config and override prod config on prod servers.

Comment: What about the opposite? If I want to have a properties file inside the web application just in case the Tomcat one can't be found. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Isn't WEB_INF/classes inside your web application?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. It looks like the easiest path to getting what I want on the Java side of the application is to use `Servlet.getServletConfig().`[`getInitParameter(parameterName)`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) e.g. getInitParameter("myApp.connectionString");

But I don't know where to set this. The [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) talk about various permutations of context.xml but I want to make sure this parameter only affects my servlet and not any others. I also don't want to locate it within my .war file so that I can keep this parameter independent of the applications (for instance if I install an upgrade).

---

**Update:** I figured it out, key/value parameters accessible by [ServletContext.getInitParameter()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) go here (or can go here) in ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml:

```
<Server port=... >
    ...
  <Service name="Catalina" ...>
    <Engine name="Catalina" ...>
      ...
      <Host name="localhost" ...>
        <Context path="/myWarFile">
          <Parameter name="foo" value="123" />
          <Parameter name="bar" value="456" />
           ...
        </Context>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

This sets two parameters, "foo" = "123", "bar" = "456" for the servlet myWarFile.war (or more accurately with the URL path `/myWarFile`) and I can get at them in Java with `Servlet.getServletConfig().getInitParameter("foo")` or `Servlet.getServletConfig().getInitParameter("bar")`.

I also looked at JIRA's server.xml entry (and [what they tell you to set it to for MySQL](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/v3.13/databases/mysql.html#N10098)), they use a `Resource` rather than a `Parameter`, not quite sure of the subtleties of this but it seems like it could be more appropriate method.

```
<Server port=... >
  <Service name="Catalina" ...>
    <Engine name="Catalina" ...>
      <Host name="localhost" ...>
        <Context path="/jira" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" 
            reloadable="false">
          <Resource name="jdbc/JiraDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="jirauser"
            password="..."
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jiradb1?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"
            maxActive="20"
            validationQuery="select 1"
          />
        </Context>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Those parameters are configured inside the servlet tag of the web.xml file, using: init-param, param-name and param-value. http://www.orionserver.com/docs/web.xml.html

Comment: *which* web.xml file? the one in my .war file or in ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf? If the former, I need to not do that, if the latter I don't understand the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you can add the path to your properties files in your `CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties` in the "common" classloader *common.loader*.