# Defining Tomcat servlet context parameters

Tags: tomcat6

Scenario:

foo.war file contains a default value of init parameter fooParam=1.

This is defined in `foo.war!WEB_INF/web.xml` which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app 
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <context-param>
      <param-name>fooParam</param-name>
      <param-value>1</param-value>
      <description>
        my parameter "fooParam"
      </description>
    </context-param>

    ...
```

OK, now I want to be able to override it in a config file in the Tomcat {$CATALINA_HOME}/conf/ directory. Where/how can I do this???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the documentation of the [Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) element:

> ### Context Parameters
>
> You can configure named values that
>   will be made visible to the web
>   application as servlet context
>   initialization parameters by nesting
>   `<Parameter>` elements inside this
>   element. For example, you can create
>   an initialization parameter like this:
>
> ```
> <Context ...>
>   ...
>   <Parameter name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated"
>          override="false"/>
>   ...
> </Context>
> ```
>
> This is equivalent to the inclusion of
>   the following element in the web
>   application deployment descriptor
>   (`/WEB-INF/web.xml`):
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>   <param-name>companyName</param-name>
>   <param-value>My Company, Incorporated</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```
>
> but does not require modification of
>   the deployment descriptor to customize
>   this value.
>
> The valid attributes for a
>   `<Parameter>` element are as follows:
>
> ...

About the `override` attribute of a `<Parameter>`, the documentation says:

> Set this to `false` if you do not want a `<context-param>` for the same parameter name, found in the web application deployment descriptor, to override the value specified here. By default, overrides are allowed.

Setting it to false should do the trick. This was the "how" part.

---

For the "where" part, read refer to the introduction of [The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html):

> **For Tomcat 6, unlike Tomcat 4.x, it is NOT recommended to place `<Context>` elements directly in the `server.xml` file.** This is because it makes modifing the Context configuration more invasive since the main `conf/server.xml` file cannot be reloaded without restarting Tomcat.
>
> **Context** elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> - In the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` file: the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps.
> - In the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml.default` file: the Context element information will be loaded by all webapps of that host.
> - In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` directory. The name of the file (less the .xml extension) will be used as the context path. Multi-level context paths may be defined using #, e.g. `foo#bar.xml` for a context path of `/foo/bar`. The default web application may be defined by using a file called ROOT.xml.
> - Only if a context file does not exist for the application in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/`, in an individual file at `/META-INF/context.xml` inside the application files. If the web application is packaged as a WAR then `/META-INF/context.xml` will be copied to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` and renamed to match the application's context path. Once this file exists, it will not be replaced if a new WAR with a newer `/META-INF/context.xml` is placed in the host's appBase.
> - Inside a Host element in the main `conf/server.xml`.
>
> With the exception of `server.xml`, files that define **Context**  elements may only define a single **Context** element.

Answer (score 0):

Argh! I thought I had asked this before. It's really hard to search on this website sometimes.

[where/how to setup configuration resources for Tomcat .war files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521957/where-how-to-setup-configuration-resources-for-tomcat-war-files)