# java - cannot find file in jersey project

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I am trying to load `Properties` from a file in a resource class of a jersey webapp. This is the resource and I followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/how-to-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("persons")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonResource {

public PersonResource() 
{
     Properties props = new Properties();
     InputStream is = PersonResource.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/test.txt");
     if(is == null) { System.out.println("Inputstream is null");}
     else 
     {
         try 
         { 
             props.load(is);
             System.out.println(props.propertyNames());
         } 
         catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
     }

}

@GET
public List<Person> getAllPersons()
{
    List<Person> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(new Person("peter", "sullivan"));
    res.add(new Person("claire", "wood"));
    return res;
}

@GET
@Path("/{fn}")
public Person getPerson(@PathParam("fn") String fn)
{
    return new Person("peter", "sullivan");
}
```

}

This is my folder structure

[image: folder structure]

where the `test.txt` is located in `WebContent/WEB-INF/`. The file is just a single line "key=value". I added the `WebContent` folder as a source folder.

When I run the app on tomcat 7, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
demo.rest.jersey.resource.PersonResource.<init>(PersonResource.java:25)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
```

Line 25 where the error occurs is `InputStream is = PersonResource.class.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("WebContent/WEB-INF/test.txt");`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using eclipse, do the right click on the test.txt file,  and press on the properties.

It opens a dialogue bow, there you will find the path of that file.  Copy that path and run it.

Comment: no that didn't work, even when tomcat runs on localhost

Answer (score 1):

The problem is around the path itself. it should be relative path.
like you have to come out from the current folder and go to the folder where we have the test.txt.

OR

copy that test.txt in the folder where you have  PersonResource .java and the path should be "test.txt"

Comment: you are partly right. The file must be in a source folder (say webapp/WEB-INF/test.txt where "webapp" is a source folder) and then you can just reference it with "WEB-INF/test.txt". However the other important bit is that you can only initialize a `File` object from the string path via  `ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader(); File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(path).getFile());`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942584/jersey-servletcontext-and-resource-loading-on-startup). This works now:

```
@Path("persons")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class PersonResource implements ServletContextListener
{

@GET
public List<Person> getAllPersons()
{
    List<Person> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(new Person("peter", "sullivan"));
    res.add(new Person("claire", "wood"));
    return res;
}

@GET
@Path("/{fn}")
public Person getPerson(@PathParam("fn") String fn)
{
    return new Person("peter", "sullivan");
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent ctxt) {
    System.out.println("Destroying context");
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent ctxt) {
    System.out.println("PersonResource initialized!");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    try(InputStream is = ctxt.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/test.txt"))
    {
        props.load(is);
        System.out.println("key= " + props.getProperty("key"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot load test.txt");
    }
}
}
```