# How to get access HttpServletRequest in constructor of resource-parentclass?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, constructor, jax-rs

I filter the BasicAuth of my REST-services and store the username in the HttpServletRequest

Related Code of the AuthFilter

```
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    public transient HttpServletRequest servletRequest;    

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) throws WebApplicationException {

        // all the auth filter actions...  

        // Set data
        servletRequest.setAttribute("auth_username", username);

        return containerRequest;
    }
}
```

I then have a resource parent class (called BaseResource with only some general attributes) and specific classes which extends it

example specific class

```
@Path("/Plant")
public class PlantResource  extends BaseResource  {

    private List<Plant> plantlist = new LinkedList<Plant>();

    @GET
    @Path("/GetPlantById/plantid/{plantid}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getPlantById(@PathParam("plantid") String plantid, @Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {

        String username = (String)hsr.getAttribute("auth_username");

        // do something 
    }
}
```

As you can see I handle the HttpServletRequest via "@Context HttpServletRequest hsr" to the function (as described in there: [Get HttpServletRequest in Jax Rs / Appfuse application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612194/get-httpservletrequest-in-jax-rs-appfuse-application)) . This works fine and I can access the data correctly!

What I want now to do is to access this Data in the constructor of the parent class, so I don't have to do it in every function of my specified resources, but in a single place

My try:

```
public class BaseResource {

    @Context protected HttpServletRequest hsr; // Also tried private and public: 

    /* ... */

    public BaseResource() {

        String username = (String)hsr.getAttribute("auth_username"); // line 96

        System.out.println("constructur of BaseResource" + username);   
    }    
}
```

But this ends up in:

```
Aug 05, 2013 3:40:18 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
Schwerwiegend: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at de.unibonn.sdb.mobilehelper.resources.BaseResource.<init>(BaseResource.java:96)
```

It looks like the HttpServletRequest isn't set there. So how can I access it in the constructor of my parent class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fields of `BaseResource` are injected after an instance is created, so you can't refer to them in the constructor itself. Either create a property method in your `BaseResource`:

```
public class BaseResource {

    @Context
    protected HttpServletRequest hsr;

    /* ... */

    protected String getUsername() {
        return (String)hsr.getAttribute("auth_username");
    }    
}
```

or create a hierarchy like:

```
public class BaseResource {

    protected HttpServletRequest hsr;

    /* ... */

    public BaseResource(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        this.hsr = hsr;

        String username = (String)hsr.getAttribute("auth_username");
        System.out.println("constructur of BaseResource" + username);   
    }    
}
```

and

```
@Path("/Plant")
public class PlantResource  extends BaseResource  {

    private List<Plant> plantlist = new LinkedList<Plant>();

    public PlantResource(@Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        super(hsr);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/GetPlantById/plantid/{plantid}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getPlantById(@PathParam("plantid") String plantid) {
        String username = (String)hsr.getAttribute("auth_username");
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea of pass up the httpServletRequest via the constructor of child class to the parent. Totally forget to this way and only thought about the constructor in parent class but it works well and my goal to avoid duplicate sourcecode is achieved!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass it up via a function.  The JAX-RS annotations like @Context aren't available in the parent, as you noted.  They are also not inherited down.  Additionally, you cannot do it at construction time since @Context references are not guaranteed to be available during construction (depends on how container creates the resources).