# How to respond to a simple sort query using JaxRS Rest?

Tags: java, jax-rs

The [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) uses the [JsonRest store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) to communicate to your server with REST calls. In the [dGrid](http://www.dgrid.io) the **column headers are sortable**. When a column is clicked, there is a call to the server with sort details. I do not know how to handle these calls for sorting in my Java code. Using **Jax-RS (Jersey 1.13)**, how do I build a restful method that matches and responds to the sort query string shown below?

For example, sorting by the "ID" column results in this http request:

```
/rest/Subcategory/?sort(-subcatId)
```

I am unclear how to extract the sort query string value using this syntax. I tried `@QueryParam("sort")` and failed. I am currently searching for sort examples in Java. I also am searching the coding conventions for Restful Services.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9612720/1653234).

Answer (score 0):

If your URL is something like :-

```
/rest/Subcategory/?sort=subCatID
```

The `@QueryParam("sort")` should work. I have not worked with Jersey much, but have used this many times in `CXF` which is also another `JAX-RS` spec implementation.

The `CXF`'s page http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html explains `Jaxrs` basics nicely. Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought the same. However, Dojo Framework uses the formatting shown above: `?sort(-subcatId)` or `?sort(+subcatId)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the @ServletRequest as a parameter of your resource method, and then retrieve the query string:

```
@GET
public Response getSubCategory(@Context HttpRequestServlet request) {
    ...
    request.getQueryString();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Dojo to send it as a query param (i.e. with the sort=+someValue or sort=-someValue make sure you set

```
"Content-Type":"application/json"
"charset":"UTF-8"

var TrackableRest = declare([Rest, Trackable]);
    var interceptStore = new TrackableRest({
        target: 'rest/intercepts/', 
        accepts: "application/json",
        sortParam: 'sort',         
        rangeStartParam: 'offset',
        rangeCountParam: 'limit',
        headers:{
            'Accept': "application/json",
            'Content-Type':"application/json",
            'charset':"UTF-8"             
        },
        idProperty: 'id'
    });
```