# Unable to sort Dgrid

Tags: json, sorting, dojo, dgrid

```
var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection]);
                    var questionGrid = new CustomGrid({
                        store: questionCacheStore,
                        columns: [
                            editor({
                                label: "Questions",
                                field: "question",
                                editor: "text",
                                editOn: "dblclick",
                                sortable:true})

                        ],
                        selectionMode: "single",
                        cellNavigation: false
                    }, "questions");
```

I am new to Dgrid. So, please do bear with me . 
i was able to populate the dgrid with a JsonStore content. But when i click on the column 'Questions', it doesn't get sorted as in local data store.instead it shows an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sort'`. Is it required to define such a method . If so, how and where should i define it ?

Comment: Use the [OnDemandGrid](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores). I had the same issue and stripped out my code line by line trying to find the issue. The only solution I came up with was changing the dependency from "dgrid/Grid" to "dgrid/OnDemandGrid".

Comment: Also, take note the dgrid will query the rest service again for sorting. For example, if your restful web service url is `/rest/questions/` and you clicked the column header for `questionId`, dgrid will query: `/rest/questions/sort(+questionId)` for ascending order. For descending order you might see `/rest/questions/sort(-questionId)`. You provide the sorting logic and return as json.

Comment: Any luck with your Grid?

Comment: yes the error at console is gone.Thank you.Now can you please tell me where i should define this sort method ?am new to J2EE as well

Answer (score 0):

I am not the person to answer your J2EE question. I asked that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695870/how-to-respond-to-a-simple-sort-query-using-jaxrs-rest) recently. The solution that I found was to [inject the HttpServletRequest directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612194/get-httpservletrequest-in-jax-rs-appfuse-application/9612720#9612720). This allowed me access to the query string parameters. From there I was able to get the sort direction (ascending, descending) and column to sort. Hopefully the snippets below will help.

**Example Grid Setup**

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Cache", 
    "dojo/store/Observable", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid", "dojo/_base/declare", "dgrid/Keyboard", 
    "dgrid/Selection", "dojo/domReady!"], 
function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache, Observable, Grid, declare, Keyboard, Selection) {

    var rest = new JsonRest({target:"/POC_Admin/rest/Subcategory/", idProperty: "subcatId"});
    var cache = new Cache(rest, new Memory({ idProperty: "subcatId" }));
    var store = new Observable(cache);
    var CustomGrid = declare([ Grid, Keyboard, Selection ]);

    var grid = new CustomGrid({
        columns: {
            subcatId: "ID",
            name: "Name"
        },
        store: store
    }, "grid");      

    grid.on("dgrid-select", function(event){
        // Report the item from the selected row to the console.
        console.log("Row selected: ", event.rows[0].data);
    });

    grid.startup();

});
```

**Example Rest GET**

```
    @Context private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    @GET
    @Path("")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
    public String getSubcategories(@QueryParam("name") String name) throws IOException {

        //Respond to a QueryString value.
        if (servletRequest.getQueryString() != null && servletRequest.getQueryString().length() > 0) {

            String querystringKey = servletRequest.getQueryString();
            System.out.println("QSKey = " + querystringKey);
            System.out.println("Substr: " + querystringKey.substring(0, 4));
            if (querystringKey.length()>4) {

                if (querystringKey.substring(0, 4).contains("sort")) {
                    //We have the sort request.
                }
            }
        }

        //Return all results otherwise from your DAO at this point
    }
```