# How to implement an function which can get the request and response information in service layer in jersey

Tags: java, rest, api, servlets, jersey

I have a rest endpoint like this

```
@Path("/keys")
public class KeysResource {

     keyService my_keyService = new keyService();
/**
 * Check if the API is alive
 * @return 204 on existing API, else the framework returns 404.
 */
@HEAD
public Response head() {
   return my_keyService.head();
}
```

And I have the keyService class like this

```
public Response head() {
   return Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).build();

   //I want to have a function like this
    keyInfo.getKeyInfo();
}
```

So in the service class, I want to have a function to get the request and response information when users calling this API. How can I get the information from the service class??

Comment: To get what *response* information? You're the one who supposed to generate the response.

Comment: What *request* information in particular? It's up to the end-point code to supply the service method with any information it needs, so the service method should have parameter for the values needed, and the end-point method can then receive provide that from any predefined JAX-RS parameters.

Comment: FYI: The service method should not return a `Response` object. The JAX-RS objects should be used only by the end-point handler methods. The service methods should be independent of JAX-RS.

Comment: So I can only get the request body and response body in the first KeysResource class, right?

Comment: That's where you can add parameters for receiving them, yes.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I still have some problems. The request information which I want to get is something like userIP, http method and timestamp. How can I get these information in the keyResource class or keyService class?

Comment: See [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9627801/5221149) in duplicate. We do provide those links so you can read find your answer there. --- What "timestamp"? HTTP requests don't have timestamps.