# How to access init-param from Jersey 2.x servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I have a RESTful service that runs as a Tomcat servlet as per the following specification in web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>User Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>demo.web.ix.users</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>myCustomParam</param-name>
        <param-value>some_value</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>User Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/ix/users/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the demo.web.ix.users package, there is class called UserService that implements the RESTful methods but does **not** extend any other class. It just features annotations (@GET, @POST, etc) which allow Jersey to pick it up.

I need to read the value of **myCustomParam** from the servlet code. I found out that calling **servletConfig.getInitParameter("myCustomParam")** would be the way to do it if the servlet extended any of the servlet classes (Generic, Http, etc).

I tried to change UserService so that it extends **org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer** but it doesn't help because the getServletConfig() method always returns null.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you say you need value *"from the servlet code"*, do you actually mean that you need the value from class `UserService`, which is not actually a **servlet**, but a rest controller?

Comment: Potential duplicate of "[Servlet init() method equivalent in JAX-RS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16809379/5221149)" or "[How to get ServeletConfig in Jersey Provider?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22265528/5221149)", or see Jersey documentation: [JAX-RS Application, Resources and Sub-Resources - 3.6. Use of @Context](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2822).

Comment: @Andreas Indeed, my problem is similar to "How to get ServeletConfig in Jersey Provider?" but why do you have to be so downvote-happy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just inject [`Configuration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration.html). You can get the values from [`getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-)

```
@Context
private Configuration config;
...

String prop = (String) config.getProperty('customProp');
```

You could also inject [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) and use its method [`getInitParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter-java.lang.String-).

`Configuration` is more portable, as it doesn't tie you to a servlet environment, for example you want to move to a grizzly container. Using `Configuration` Jersey will just transfer all the init-params to the `Configuration` when you are in a servlet environment. If you are not in a servlet environment then there are other ways to set up the property, aside from the init-param. See link below.

**See also:**

- [Working with Jersey Configuration Properties](https://psamsotha.github.io/jersey/2015/12/27/jersey-configuration-properties.html)