# getting the HTTP URL from inside a JAX-RS resource

Tags: jersey, tomcat7, jax-rs

From inside my JAX-RS (Jersey) resource I need to get the base URL of the Jersey `Servlet` that's "publishing" that resource. I tried injecting `ServletContext` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814788/274677), and then doing a:

```
return servletContext.getResource("/").toString();
```

to get the "base" URL of the Jersey `Servlet` for this resource.

However the above code returns a value like:

```
jndi:/localhost/jax-rs-tomcat-test/
```

where I was expecting something more like:

```
http://localhost:8080/jax-rs-tomcat-test/jax-rs
```

Where "`jax-rs`" is what I have in my web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>  
   <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>  
   <url-pattern>/jax-rs/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

That is, there are four "differences": (a) protocol, (b) single instead of double slash after the protocol, (c) port number and (d) missing URL pattern for triggering the Jersey servlet. So, how do I get:

1. the base `http://` URL of the Jersey servlet
2. the full URL that triggered a particular `@GET` or `@POST` annotated method ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [UriInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html). Inject it into your resource using `@Context`:

```
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
```

and then you can call `getBaseUri()` method:

```
uriInfo.getBaseUri();
```