# Path of files in Tomcat webapplication

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to load a few parameters from a `xml` file on my Tomcat server. let´s say thats the folder structure:

```
 Tomcat
 |-webapps
   |-MyWebApp.war
   |-MyWebApp //(Source files)
      |-META-INF
      |-WEB-INF
         |-configFile.xml
```

I tried several different methods like

```
File inputfile = new File("/MyWebApp/WEB-INF/configFile.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputfile);
```

which just delivered a `filemissing exception`...

So the question is:

**HOW do I have to set the path in my Java code to refer to files on my Tomcat ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid to use files in a web application.

Here is the way to go: You need to obtain a `ServletContext` (e.g. being inside a `Servlet`).

Then use

```
ServletContext context = ...
InputStream in = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/configFile.xml");
```

to open an `InputStream` to your XML file and pass it to the `DocumentBuilder`.

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in);
```

Comment: How can I get the ServletContext ? I just have a simple REST service class which calls my (service)class to open the file and get the prams.

Comment: @JohnDizzle inject the context into your service class, e.g. for JAX-RS see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814517/get-servletcontext-on-tomcat-from-jax-rs-jersey

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
File inputfile = new File("/WEB-INF/configFile.xml");
```

OR

```
File inputfile = new File("../WEB-INF/configFile.xml");
```