# Tomcat - Differentiate between DEV and PROD server at runtime

Tags: apache, tomcat, server, config

I am new to server management of Apache Tomcat. Hence this question may sound very basic. I have 2 servers(DEV and PROD) loaded with default configuration of Apache tomcat and MySQL. Both are identical in terms of their setup.

Now I want to put my WAR file on both of the machines using the MANAGER PANEL, and the application should automatically know in which environment it is running, so that it automatically selects the level of logging it has to run.

This is because I want detailed logging in DEV and less logging in PROD, but doing this using a flag in code is ok, but I often forget before creating the WRA file and then after putting the code on the server, it creates a lot of logs which I don't want in case of PROD.

I think it can be done using one time configuration in some config file of Tomcat, but I don't know what change in which file.

Request you to please help me on this.

Comment: Perhaps see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626018/defining-tomcat-servlet-init-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you David for your suggestion. That really gave the head start. But to be precise and detailed, here are the links that helped

**Changes to context.xml taken from here**

http://www.coderanch.com/t/512855/Tomcat/access-context-xml-parameter

**Changes to code taken from here**

[Get ServletContext in JAX-RS resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814517/get-servletcontext-on-tomcat-from-jax-rs-jersey)
and 
http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-get-context-param-value-in-java/

Finally I was able to achieve what I wanted to. Earlier I was not having the correct keywords to look for over the internet as a result I was stuck. Thank you David.