# AWS Lambda - MySQL caching

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

I have Lambda that uses RDS. I wanted to improve it and use the Lambda connection caching. I have found several articles, and implemented it on my side, best to my knowledge. But now, I am not sure it is this the rigth way to go.

I have Lambda (running Node 8), which has several files used with require. I will start from the main function, until I reach the MySQL initializer, which is exact path. All will be super simple, showing only to flow of the code that runs MySQL:

**Main Lambda:**

```
const jobLoader = require('./Helpers/JobLoader');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const emarsysPayload = event.Records[0];
    let validationSchema;

    const body = jobLoader.loadJob('JobName');
     ...
    return;
...//
```

**Job Code:**

```
const MySQLQueryBuilder = require('../Helpers/MySqlQueryBuilder');

exports.runJob = async (params) => {
      const data = await MySQLQueryBuilder.getBasicUserData(userId);
```

**MySQLBuilder:**

```
const mySqlConnector = require('../Storage/MySqlConnector');

    class MySqlQueryBuilder {
        async getBasicUserData (id) {
            let query = `
    SELECT * from sometable WHERE id= ${id} 
    `;

            return mySqlConnector.runQuery(query);
        }
    }
```

**And Finally the connector itself:**

```
const mySqlConnector = require('promise-mysql');
const pool = mySqlConnector.createPool({
        host: process.env.MY_SQL_HOST,
        user: process.env.MY_SQL_USER,
        password: process.env.MY_SQL_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.MY_SQL_DATABASE,
        port: 3306
    });

    exports.runQuery = async query => {
        const con = await pool.getConnection();
        const result = con.query(query);
        con.release();
        return result;
    };
```

I know that measuring performance will show the actual results, but today is Friday, and I will not be able to run this on Lambda until the late next week... And really, it would be awesome start of the weekend knowing I am in right direction... or not.

Thank for the inputs.

Comment: I didn't actually get your question. You want to know how to achieve caching with Lambda?

Comment: Yes. The code above is my attempt to create caching on Lambda.

Comment: You mean you're requiring your connection before your function is executed, right? when I first read cache I thought about caching results for a certain time.

Comment: Yes. I would want to avoid connection creation for every single query, and rather rely on Lambda container cache.

Comment: Ok, I'll elaborate an answer.

Comment: Happy to continue the discussion should you have more questions or in case I wasn't clear enough!

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, it does explain a lot. However, I wanted to achieve something mentioned in this article: https://spotinst.com/blog/2017/11/19/best-practices-serverless-connection-pooling-database/

Comment: Thanks! I have edited my answer with a few more bytes of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing would be to understand how `require` works in NodeJS. I do recommend you go through this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8) if you're interested in knowing more about it.

Now, once you have required your connection, you have it for good and it won't be required again. This matches what you're looking for as you don't want to overwhelm your database by creating a new connection every time.

But, there is a problem...

**Lambda Cold Starts**

Whenever you invoke a Lambda function for the first time, it will spin up a container with your function inside it and keep it alive for approximately 5 mins. It's very likely (although not guaranteed) that you will hit the same container every time as long as you are making 1 request at a time. But what happens if you have 2 requests at the same time? Then another container will be spun up in parallel with the previous, already warmed up container. You have just created another connection on your database and now you have 2 containers. Now, guess what happens if you have 3 concurrent requests? Yes! One more container, which equals one more DB connection.

As long as there are new requests to your Lambda functions, by default, they will scale out to meet demand (you can configure it in the console to limit the execution to as many concurrent executions as you want - respecting your Account limits)

You cannot safely make sure you have a fixed amount of connections to your Database by simply **requiring** your code upon a Function's invocation. The good thing is that this is not your fault. This is just how Lambda functions behave.

**...one other approach is**

to cache the data you want in a real caching system, like [ElasticCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/), for example. You could then have one Lambda function be triggered by a [CloudWatch Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) that runs in a certain frequency of time. This function would then query your DB and store the results in your external cache. This way you make sure your DB connection is only opened by one Lambda at a time, because it will respect the CloudWatch Event, which turns out to run only once per trigger.

**EDIT**: after the OP sent a link in the comment sections, I have decided to add a few more info to clarify what the mentioned article wants to say

From the article:

> "Simple. You ARE able to store variables outside the scope of our
>   handler function. This means that you are able to create your DB
>   connection pool outside of the handler function, which can then be
>   shared with each future invocation of that function. This allows for
>   pooling to occur."

And this is exactly what you're doing. And this works! But the problem is if you have N connections (Lambda Requests) at the same time. If you don't set any limits, by default, up to 1000 Lambda functions can be spun up concurrently. Now, if you then make another 1000 requests simultaneously in the next 5 minutes, it's very likely you won't be opening any new connections, because they have already been opened on previous invocations and the containers are still alive.

Comment: Great answer!!!. I will control my Concurrency in the Lambda to some normal and acceptable value. I am so happy that I got it right. Now I can go and have a decent weekend. Thank you Sir!

Comment: Thank you very much. You are more than welcome of course. Prost :)

Comment: One more thing. In your answer you mentioned: 'Again, you can check out my GitHub for examples'... could you please provide a link to them?

Comment: That was a copy and paste from the article you sent. I think it was in the last paragraph or something

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above by [Thales Minussi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947780/1416021) but for a Python Lambda. I am using PyMySQL and to create a connection pool I added the connection code above the handler in a Lambda that fetches data. Once I did this, I was not getting any new data that was added to the DB after an instance of the Lambda was executed. I found bugs reported [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/76) and [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42197) that are related to this issue.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974169/how-to-disable-query-cache-with-mysql-connector) that worked for me was to add a `conn.commit()` after the SELECT query execution in the Lambda.

According to the PyMySQL [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit), `conn.commit()` is supposed to commit any changes, but a `SELECT` does not make changes to the DB. So I am not sure exactly why this works.